# Can Juniper SSG be used as DNS recursor?

Tags: domain-name-system, juniper, screenos

As per title.
e.g.

```
1. client asks example.com <--> Juniper_SSG_140
2. Juniper_SSG_140 <--> DNS root servers
3.                 <--> Specific DNS returned by root server
4. client receives answer from Juniper_SSG_140
5. Juniper_SSG_140 caches the answer for perf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the SSG series can perform DNS lookups, but doing so only using forwarders and not root hints.

See screenshot below... these are ALL the configuration options available.

[image: SSG DNS Configuration Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

@alex you can configure per domain dns forwarding and/or a catchall option, yo to  **Network > DNS > Proxy** and mark: "**Initialize Proxy DNS Server**" and "**Enable Proxy DNS Server**", click on **Apply**.

Then click in **New** and add the domain name that you want to forward (***use * to forward all requests***), configure the **primary**, **secondary** and **tertiary** DNS IP Address. Optionally select the Interface when all this request will get out.

Then, you need to go to **Network > Interfaces** Edit the interface where you want to set the dns proxy, mark **DNS Proxy** option, and that's it!, you got it.

On the cli you can type (:

```
set dns proxy
set dns proxy enable
set dns server-select domain * primary-server x.x.x.x secondary-server y.y.y.y tertiary-server z.z.z.z
set interface ethernet#/# proxy dns
```